# Git Squash Merge on two branches making a mess

Tags: git, github, git-merge

My repository has two protected branches: `staging` and `master`. And as the name suggests, `staging` goes to Stage and `master` goes to Production. Only `staging` can be merged to `master`, no other branch should be.
Both the branches are protected and can only be merged into with valid approvals.

We had enabled only Squash and Merge in the repo. Merging feature branches in `staging` is all good, and squash works perfect for us. But after testing on Stage once we want to merge into `master`, doing a `squash` make things complicated. Now `staging` and `master` has a commit each that the other doesn't. What is the best practice around this use case?

Taking a branch out of `staging`, merging `master` into it and pushing it to `staging` doesn't help because the commit on `master` (lets say A) still doesn't go into `staging` as A (but as B, a separate squashed commit). Leads to conflicts.

Squash into `staging` and merge-commit from `staging` into `master` works, but there's no way to restrict people to use squash into `staging` in that way, and people hardly check on what they chose while merging.

My need is to have two protected branches. I want squash on my `staging`, but there isn't an option to disable/enable that on selective branches on Github.

Comment: If you migrate features selectively to master after they have been tested in staging, do regular merges, not squash merges, of feature branches. Get your team to behave and not do squash merges without thinking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [GitLab squash and merge strategy](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/squash_and_merge.html) makes sense when merging on staging, but it does not seem useful on `master`.

I would use the "Encourage" option at the project level: Squashing is allowed and selected by default, but can be disabled.

Since people hardly check on what they chose while merging, they will use the default ("squasing").
And the few authorized to merge to `master` will be more conscious of this option, and disable it when merging to the main branch.

Comment: does that mean I can't have dev branch with all the single commits, and then master with features squashed into a single commit?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh You can squash merge if you want. As long as the source branch is rebased first on top of the target branch, which is a best practice. You revalidate that everything works locally, then force push. And finally merge. Or squash merge.

Comment: doesn't the rebase produce plenty of merge issues?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh Only if you had concurrent modifications on common files between the two branches. If not, then no. No merge issues.

Comment: Situation: developing feature 1, changing file `a.txt`. Multiple commits, (squash) merge into master. Developing feature 2, also changing file `a.txt`, what now?

Comment: @Mahrkeenerh rebase `feat2` on top of `master` (although these days it is called `main`). That way, `a.txt` get `feat1`, and re-validate that `feat2` still works.

Comment: won't the rebase have merge conflicts? As the `dev` branch already has all `main` commits, just not as a single one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245434/discussion-between-vonc-and-mahrkeenerh).